# Install docker 1.11 on Fedora 21

Tags: docker, installation, fedora-21

I need to install docker 1.11.x on Fedora 21. I'm not familiar with this distro so have followed the instructions on the [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/installation/linux/fedora/) but only 1.9.1 is available.

Any ideas on how to install 1.11? Perhaps I need to point to a different repo?

Comment: `docker-1.11.2` is e.g. here : https://github.com/docker/docker/releases → → One third down the page ...

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -o docker.tar.gz https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.11.2.tgz
tar xzvf docker.tar.gz
sudo mv docker/* /usr/bin/
```

With this code your are downloading the binaries compiled for your by Docker and you are coping that into a $PATH dir in order to use that around your system.

Answer (score -1):

I simply needed to [update](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) fedora to 22